# JVM Options. Как указать конфигурационный файл для Log4j?

Tags: java, glassfish, log4j

Нужно сделать лог

Делал как в [этом примере](https://blogs.oracle.com/naman/entry/configure_log4j_for_use_in).

```
log4j.configuration=file:///${com.sun.aas.instanceRoot}/config/log4j.properties
```

На локальной машине работает. Но когда залил на удаленный сервер, то ни в `log4j.log` ни в `server.log` ничего не записывает.

На удаленке несколько истансов Glassfish. Мне кажется проблема в этом.

Путь: `/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1`

Кроме `opt` есть еще несколько директорий с glassfish3.

Вопрос: каким должно быть свойство?

Если проблема в другом, то подскажите.

---

Сам файл log4j.properties:

```
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, FILE
log4j.logger.myapp=DEBUG
log4j.appender.FILE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender 
log4j.appender.FILE.File=/opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/log4j.log
log4j.appender.FILE.MaxFileSize=1MB 
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.FILE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout 
log4j.appender.FILE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{DATE} %-5p %c{1} : %m%n
```

Попробовал записать в server.log - получилось, но в log4j.log не получается

Comment: прав-то хватает на запись?

Comment: Прости, о каких правах идет речь?

Comment: @mr.Ball процессу java на запись в /opt/glassfish3/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/log4j.log

Comment: Чаще всего запись в файл не осуществляется по той причине, что у пользователя, запустившего процесс (в вашем случае - JVM) не хватает прав на запись указанной локации файловой системы. Проверьте владельца директории для лога и убедитесь, что пользователь, от которого запускается приложение, имеет права на запись в эту директорию.

Comment: Да, права на запись есть